# Can we bind Response data to Angular view if interface values are not matching?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, data-binding

i am developing Mean Stack Application, i was trying to bind response array data to my angular view, Angular  application`s interface  and API use different model value names , so is it possible to  bind incoming API`s data to bind without changing the values name ,

This data i am receiving from APIS,

```
"_id": "5ddfc13d92eb1e27640b42b2",
        "degprog": "MCS",
        "session": "2017-21",
        "semester": "2nd",
        "c_code": "55",
        "c_title": "SE",
        "c_hours": "4234",
        "m_quiz": 30,
        "m_assign": 20,
        "c_coordinator": "Ali Abbas",
        "c_url": "www.CsinBestWay.com",
        "c_catelog": "catelog dont know",
        "c_tbook": "Cs In BestWay",
        "c_reference": "CsinBestWay",
        "c_goals": "To understand students ",
        "c_pre": "Special None",
        "m_lab": null,
        "m_mid": 75,
        "m_final": 75,
        "m_total": 200,
```

**and this is my Angular interface**

```
export interface CourseInterface {
    _id:any,
    degreeProgram:String,
    session:String,
    semester:String,
    courseTitle:String,
    courseCode:String,
    creditHours:String,
    pre:String,
    quiz:String,
    midTerm:String,
    finalTerm:String,
    assignment:String,
    lab:String,
    totalMarks:String,
    courseCoordinator:String,
    url:String,
    currentCatelogDescription:String,
    textBook:String,
    referenceMaterial:String,
    courseGoals:String}
```

*And this is the function in which i want to get data*

```
getCourses(techId:any){
    this.courseService.showCourses(techId).subscribe(
      (Courses)=> this.course = Courses,
      (err:any)=>{
        console.log(err);
      }
   )}
```

When i try to bind in html like this(course?.courseTitle) nothing fetches, if i use console.log(this.course) complete course details displays proper, (as i show  on the top)

Comment: No you can't. You have to use a helper function to map the values to the interface types and only then it will work

Comment: the data wont be mapped to the interface. they differ in property names.

Comment: do you mean i have to map  like=> this.courseTitle = res.c_title? and so on ?

Comment: you just need to create the interface with same property names as the json response keys

Comment: Thank you dear i understood